# "Something went wrong" when setting up POP account for outlook.com

Tags: microsoft-outlook, pop3

I'm trying to set up a POP account for my outlook.com email address in Outlook 2016. I followed the instructions [here](https://www.lifewire.com/outlook-pop-server-settings-1170670). So I'm using these settings:

[image]

Outlook then asks me for my password. After 3 attempts (yes, I'm sure I'm using the correct password), Outlook says "Something went wrong".

Though the article I referred to is quite recent it is possible that Microsoft changed the parameters, so I went to look at [this Microsoft web page](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-your-Outlook-com-account-in-Outlook-for-Windows-642c1902-bdd9-4dc3-abe7-76d60b148b23?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US), but this contains hardly any information, and none about POP accounts.

So, should my account work with the above settings, or how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you enable the "POP options" in the Outlook.com web interface for your mailbox?

Comment: @Kinnectus - No, I hadn't. Didn't know about it. I enabled POP now, but it's still the same. Thanks for your comment, though.

Comment: Is the client getting your emails or is it receiving but not sending? Also, are you using a work network or is this your home ISP?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I can send mail to the account, and read it on outlook.live.com. Since I can't set up the account on the client (Outlook) I don't know if it would receive. It's my home PC, and the other email accounts (on 2 other ISPs) are just peachy.